# replace urls in string preg_replace regex php

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I need to replace urls in my content with another url prefix: 
i.e. if the current url is `<a href="http://myoldurl.com">link</a>` and I want to change it to:
`<a href="http://myurl.com/create/?url=http://myoldurl.com">link</a>` how can replace my links using preg_replace?

Answer (score 1):

### Disclaimer:

It is always best to use a dedicated parser when working with (X)HTML. There are certainly files containing markup that can cause this regex solution to fail. Evil edge case strings placed inside comments, CDATA sections, scripts, styles and/or attribute values can trip it up. (Although these should be very rare.)

### That said...

Many here will tell you to NEVER use regex with HTML. However, this question involves a very specific target string, and a carefully crafted regex solution can work pretty well for this one-shot task at hand. Here is how I would do it:

```php
$text = preg_replace('%
    # Match A element open tag up through specific HREF value.
    (                     # $1: Everything up to target HREF value.
      <A                  # Literal start of A element open tag.
      (?:                 # Zero or more attributes before HREF.
        \s+               # Whitespace required before each attribute.
        (?!HREF)          # Assert this attribute is not HREF.
        [\w\-.:]+         # Required attribute name.
        (?:               # Attribute value is optional.
          \s*=\s*         # Attrib value separated by =.
          (?:             # Group attrib value alternatives.
            "[^"]*"       # Either double quoted value,
          | \'[^\']*\'    # or single quoted value,
          | [\w\-.:]+     # or unquoted value.
          )               # End attrib value alternatives.
        )?                # Attribute value is optional.
      )*                  # Zero or more attributes before HREF.
      \s+                 # Whitespace required before HREF attribute.
      HREF                # HREF attribute name.
      \s*=\s*             # Value separated by =, optional whitespace.
    )                     # End $1: Everything up to target HREF value.
    ([\'"])               # $2: HREF attrib value opening quote.
    http://myoldurl\.com  # Target URL to be replaced.
    .*?                   # Any path/query/fragment on target URL.
    \2                    # HREF attrib value matching closing quote.
    %xi',
    '$1"http://myurl.com/create/?url=http://myoldurl.com"',
    $text);
```

This will replace the target URL only when inside the `HREF` attribute of `A` link tags (with the value wrapped in either single or double quotes). It will also strip any path/query/fragment that may be appended to the old target URLs. It allows any number of other tag attributes to appear before the `HREF` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Will replace every `http://myoldurl.com` in every link in `$string` by `http://myurl.com/create/?url=http://myoldurl.com`:

```
$string = preg_replace("/href=\"http:\/\/myoldurl\.com/i", "href=\"http://myurl.com/create/?myoldurl.com", $string);
```

Comment: `str_replace()` should be sufficient here :)

Comment: The title of the question asked for `preg_replace`, but you're right, of course. Since it's URLs, I'd use `str_ireplace()` though.